# How can I control when render three js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

All examples that I saw, uses a loop structure to render the scene, like that:

```
renderer.render(cena, camera);

function render(){
    renderer.render(cena, camera);
    //code to render
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

But I want to control the rendering in another structure, only when I interact with a thing... like

```
while(true){
//code - operations
alert('press ok to another step'); // or wait 2 sec
renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
```

What is the correct method to do this?

Comment: You could, but generally you really want to keep it inside the requestAnimationFrame() loop. You could always make the changes outside the loop. Could you clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also it's usually a good idea to steer clear of `while(true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if you want, you can call renderer.render at anytime, although it would probably be a lot better to render it in the requestAnimationFrame() (much better performance).
If you really have a need to change something that you don't want to be renderer (say, several async functions modifying scene object), you can always do something like this.

```
function render(){
    //code to update scene
    if (toRender) renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

Set `toRender` to false while you're updating the scene, this prevent the renderer from re-drawing your scene, then set `toRender` back to true to have it draw the scene in the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

as shown in this example, you can simply call renderer.render()
http://threejs.org/examples/#raytracing_sandbox